# WPF Gridview bind to columns

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

Is it possible to bind objects to gridview columns, instead of rows?
I want to have te following:

```
            Tom     Jan     Wim
LastName    Last1   Last2   Last3
Age         18      20      23      
Number      1       2       3
```

A list of objects (Tom, Jan and Wim) must be binded to column 1-3.
The first column must be frozen for scrolling and dragging.
The three data columns can be dragged to reorder them.

Can somebody help me out to start developing this?

Comment: check other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010652/how-to-correctly-bind-an-object-to-a-wpf-datagrid surely the DataGrid supports binding to list or array of objects, not only DataSet/DataTable

Comment: I know that Lists can be bound to rows. But what I want is to bind a list and show each element in a different column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2008/09/22/lt-howto-gt-replace-listview-columns-with-rows-lt-howto-gt.aspx

That link might be just what you are looking for, not with a GridView but a ListView, though.